# Grails springSecurityService injection in domain class (NULL)

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, grails-domain-class

when I inject springSecurityService into Grails User domain class it is always null:

I tried:

```
def springSecurityService
static transients = ['springSecurityService']
```

or

```
def transient springSecurityService
static transients = ['springSecurityService']
```

but it the same, so I cannot use springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)

Any ideas? Why it's not injected?

I found a decision. I commented out the call to this() in the parameterized constructor.

```
User(String name, String email) {
    //this()
    this.name = name
    this.email = email
}
```

and this breaks a Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 2):

This is documented [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/domainClasses.html) (see the note starting with "Where practical, the generated domain classes include a parameterized constructor.").

You can remove the parameterized constructors if you want, but you can't use them without the `this()` call to the generated default constructor without losing dependency injection.

IntelliJ incorrectly flags the call to `this()` as invalid and I reported it as a bug in their issue tracker. It's due to be fixed for the upcoming version 15 release.

Comment: Link broken, reload it plz

Answer (score 0):

So far nothing is solved in intellij 15 EAP!

But it could be solved by simply adding a default constructor

```
class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

transient springSecurityService

String username
String password
boolean enabled = true
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

User() {
}

User(String username, String password) {
    this()
    this.username = username
    this.password = password
}
...
}
```

Then Intellij does not bring up that error anymore.

Comment: Yes, so did I.    We are waiting for intellij  15 release.